# UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert or UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I have data edit controller similar to the `EditableDetailView` sample from the SDK. The view shows only the fields with values in the non-editing mode and in editing mode it adds the unpopulated fields too as placeholders. Unlike the SDK example the set of fields is fixed so no new placeholers have to be added during edit.

My question is whether

- Should I should place the green + Insert next to my empty field
  placeholders?
  (OR)
- A click the + would populate the placeholder next to it, but it would
  not add a new empty placeholder.

The HIG is not clear on this topic.

If I do add the + it looks better because all fields have an indicator (red - or green +), but I'm concerned that the '+' action does not actually add a new placeholder. If I leave the + out it looks odd as some fields have the red - and other have nothing.

Comment: If you can't add new fields (with insert), what does "deleting" a field do?

Comment: 'delete' clears the field in the model and immediately removes it from the view. On the next edit of the item that field would show up as an empty placeholder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to the UI&UX Stack Exchange.